# Display table css float to right

Tags: css, responsive

I have 2 table-cell as demo below. I wanted to make the left block (white block) to place in right place and the right block in the left place without removing table-cell.

The idea is I want to put the white block on the top of black block in responsive. Just like the float left and float right.

Here is the [`Jsfiddle Demo`](https://jsfiddle.net/mgpu4nqs/1/)

Thanks!

Comment: sorry here are the examples : [link](https://jsfiddle.net/mgpu4nqs/1/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to include float:left and float:right to the layers and include the property  box-sizing:border-box to the style .table-cell

https://jsfiddle.net/MAXXALANDER/mgpu4nqs/3/

```
.table-cell{
 display:table-cell;
  width:50%;
  padding:5px;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
```